# Android: Something similar to CALayer?

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I'm going to port an iOS app to Android. The app has a part, in which an UIImageView's image is composed dynamically from various CALayers. In other words - it is a radar simulation. Some CALayers are rotating, some are fixed, some points of interest are positioned dynamically according to their distance and heading from the center of the view (my position).

Q: How could that be done similarly in Android?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what framerate you require, but if that's not too high you can keep it fairly simple: Use a FrameLayout, and a nested list of ImageViews for the static and rotating images. To rotate images, you can use an Animation (see ImageView.startAnimation).
For the points-of-interest layer you will probably need a custom View, and override its onDraw() method to add your POIs.